# Why can I not cast a double object to a byte?

Tags: c#, casting, c#-2.0, type-conversion

The circumstances around that brought this up are complicated but I've trimmed my problem down to it's essence. I have a `byte` value that is placed into `double` variable. Which is then stored in a `object` variable. When I have access to this object variable I want to cast it back to a byte. Here is a short code example of my problem:

```
byte originalValue = 23;
double valueAsDouble = originalValue;

// These work without issue
byte valueByte = (byte)valueAsDouble;
int valueInt = (int)valueAsDouble;
object valueObject = valueAsDouble;

// Both of these lines throw and InvalidCastException
int valueReconvertToInt = (int)valueObject;
byte valueReconvertToByte = (byte)valueObject;
```

My question has 2 parts I guess. Why is this not allowed? Unless I'm mistaken the `object` is just a wrapper around the `double` so shouldn't I be able to cast it the same?

My second question was going to be is there some generic work around I could use when I want to cast such a value to a `byte` or `int` (or some other datatype I could cast normally cast from a `double`) but I thought of a couple. Which would be best, to use [Convert.ChangeType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), cast the `object` to a `double` before casting to a to the desired type, or some other solution I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper workaround I think it should be to use `Convert.ToByte(valueObject)` to retrieve the value from type object directly as a byte. It does perform the proper casting and returns a plain byte in one step.

About why it can't a straight cast directly, I'm not really sure, but I guess it has to do with the value object being boxed when stored in an `object` variable, then it must be unboxed previously, and that unbox requires to be done to the same type it was originally, or a compatible one. Byte isn't compatible with double (as it has a wider range), so you can only unbox to a double (since the value is really a double), and then cast that double to a byte. The `Convert` Class seems to do all that internally.

The unboxing reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simply because it isn't a byte. It's a double. Extract the double, then cast it to byte as before:

```
byte valueReconvertToByte = (byte)((double)valueObject);
```

Comment: I mention this as a workaround in my question. And in your answer you say I can't cast it because "it's a double" but then say a double can be cast to a byte. Or are you saying this is the preferred solution, and if so, why?